# Visualize high dimensional field arrows?

Tags: python, matlab, visualization, vector, multidimensional-array

I have a big list of tuples (a, b), where both a and b are 9-dimensional vectors from the same space. This essentially encodes states of a system and some transitions. I would like to visualize the field described by these tuples, as arrows pointing from a->b, either in 2D or 3D. One of my problems however is that this is not a well-behaved vector field (not continuous) but I have reasons to believe that it can probably be laid out nicely, even in 2D.

Does anyone know of a toolbox (for matlab/python) or program that can do this? This would presumably first involve some kind of dimensionality reduction on a and b and then plot little arrows from one point to another.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, turns out MATLAB can do this but it's not very pretty.
It basically boils down to doing PCA, and then using the quiver function to do the plotting:
My matrix X here contains starting points of my high dimensional nodes in odd rows, and ending points in even rows. Then:

```
[COEFF, SCORE]= princomp(zscore(X));

x=SCORE(1:2:end,1);
y=SCORE(1:2:end,2);
z=SCORE(1:2:end,3);
u=SCORE(2:2:end,1);
v=SCORE(2:2:end,2);
w=SCORE(2:2:end,3);

quiver3(x,y,z,u-x,v-y,w-z,0);
```

The downside is that I can't find a good way to color the edges, so I get a huge mess if I just do it trivially. Ah well, good enough for now!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this answers your question or not, but you may want to look at [Recurrence Plots](http://www.recurrence-plot.tk/rp-tutorial.php). If this is what you're after, then you wont need any additional Matlab toolboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Matlab toolbox of dimension reduction algorithms. I haven't worked with it, but I have worked with dimension reduction, and it seems like a manifold charting/local coordinates algorithm would be able to extract a low-dimensional representation.

[TU Delft Dim. Red. Toolbox](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/19j49/Matlab_Toolbox_for_Dimensionality_Reduction.html)